# Threshold for allowed amount of failed Hyperdrive runs

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Because "reasons", we know that when we use `azureml-sdk`'s `HyperDriveStep` we expect a number of `HyperDrive` runs to fail -- normally around 20%. How can we handle this without failing the entire `HyperDriveStep` (and then all downstream steps)? Below is an example of the pipeline.

I thought there would be an [`HyperDriveRunConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.hyperdrive.hyperdriverunconfig?view=azure-ml-py) param to allow for this, but it doesn't seem to exist. Perhaps this is controlled on the Pipeline itself with the [`continue_on_step_failure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline(class)?view=azure-ml-py#remarks) param?

The workaround we're considering is to catch the failed run within our `train.py` script and manually log the primary_metric as zero.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your question.

I'm assuming that HyperDriveStep is one of the steps in your Pipeline and that you want the remaining Pipeline steps to continue, when HyperDriveStep fails, is that correct?
Enabling continue_on_step_failure, should allow the rest of the pipeline steps to continue, when any single steps fails.

Additionally, the HyperDrive run consists of multiple child runs, controlled by the HyperDriveConfig. If the first 3 child runs explored by HyperDrive fail (e.g. with user script errors), the system automatically cancels the entire HyperDrive run, in order to avoid further wasting resources.

Are you looking to continue other Pipeline steps when the HyperDriveStep fails? or are you looking to continue other child runs within the HyperDrive run, when the first 3 child runs fail?

Thanks!

Comment: just added more context. do the 3 failed child runs have to happen consecutively? Is there a way to adjust this number? Or change the failure requirements?

Comment: to be clear i'm interested in 
> continuing other child runs within the HyperDrive run when the first 3 child runs fail?

Comment: currently, there isn't a way to conifgure the # failed child runs, before the HyperDrive run fails.

Just curious though, why you would want to continue more child runs even after the 1st 3 child runs fail. Typically this happens if the script used by all child runs has an error or some other issue that might cause all child runs to fail anyway. Is your scenario different in some way where it's likely that other child runs will succeed even despite the first 3 child runs failing?